# Need Clarification regarding Graph Api

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

Now if a new mail comes into my email. What will the Graph API do, will it send message id of the mail into the notification URL because we need message id to use this endpoint - ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages /{id} )to get the required details of the mail. I actually want to know what it will push into the notification URL if a new mail comes or an event is created.

I have created Subscription using these steps:

1. The client sends a subscription (POST) request for a specific resource.
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
   Content-Type: application/json
   {
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/notificationClient",
   "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
   "expirationDateTime": "2016-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
   "clientState": "SecretClientState"
   }
2. Microsoft Graph verifies the request.
   •   If the request is valid, Microsoft Graph sends a validation token to the notification URL.
   https://{notificationUrl}?validationToken={opaqueTokenCreatedByMicrosoftGraph}

•   If the request is invalid, Microsoft Graph sends an error response with code and details.
3.  The client sends the validation token back to Microsoft Graph.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: text/plain
{
 "statusCode": "200 ",
 " validationToken ” : 
 }
4.  The Microsoft Graph sends a response back to the client
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 252

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
"id": "7f105c7d-2dc5-4530-97cd-4e7ae6534c07",
  "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
 "applicationId": "24d3b144-21ae-4080-943f-7067b395b913",
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "clientState": "secretClientValue",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
  "expirationDateTime": "2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
 "creatorId": "8ee44408-0679-472c-bc2a-692812af3437"
}